# asymptotic and monotonically increasing properties of prime factorization function?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, prime-factorization

### Questions

We define $A(x)= \text{number of prime factors of x}$

For example $A(2 \times 3^2) = 3$

I noticed when
$s_k = \frac{N!}{\prod_j n_j}$ and $\sum_{j} n_j = N$

$$ s_1 < s_2 \implies A(s_1) < A(s_2)$$

Why is this so?

Also What is the asymptotic relation of $A(x)$ as $x \to \infty$?

### My attempt for asymptotic relation

$S(x)=A(1)x + A(2)x^2 + A(3)x^3 + \dots$

$$G(x)=\frac{S(x)}{1-x} = A(1!)x + A(2!)x^2 + A(3!)x^3 + \dots$$

We note $A(n!)$ corresponds to the sequence:  A022559

Using the result from there

$$ A(n!) \sim \ln\ln(n) + B_2 n + O(n)$$

### Relevance

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233634/number-theoretic-loophole-allows-alternative-definition-of-entropy

Comment: In your def'n of $s_k$ there is no $k$ on the RHS and no specification of what the $n_j$ are, nor what set of $j$ they belong to, or are summed or multipled over.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Let $N = 8$ and $s_1 = \binom83 = 56$, $s_2 = \binom84 = 70$, then $A(s_1) = 4 > 3 =  A(s_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

There obviously cannot be an asymptotic limit of your $A(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ because $A(n)=1$ whenever $n$ is prime and yet there are some $n$ like $2^k$ for which $A(n)$ can be arbitrarily large.

Nonetheless, if we look at Hardy and Wright's *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* 5th ed. (1980), sections 22.10-22.11, we see that $A(n)$ is called there $\Omega(n)$.  We are told that "the number of $n$, not exceeding $x$, for which $$|\Omega(n)-\log\log n|>(\log\log n)^{1/2+\delta}$$
is $o(x)$ for every positive $\delta$." In other words, $\log\log n$ is a good approximation to $\Omega(n)$ for most $n$.

Comment: Thank you .... Can you also respond to why attempt will be inadequate?

Comment: The attempt, which you added to the question after I wrote out (or started) my answer, does not make sense to me because something $O(n)$ is potentially a lot bigger than $\log\log n$; in fact what you write could just be $A(n)=O(n)$ which is true but uninteresting.  A somewhat similar result is given in Hardy and Wright theorem 430, $\sum_{n\le x} \Omega(n)=x\log \log x + B_2 x + o(x)$.  A022559 is the sum in Hardy and Wright for $x$ an integer.  A similar result appears in OEIS for A022559.  The sum is attributed to Hardy and Ramanujan.